# How do you de/serialize a monobehaviour class?

Tags: unity, serialization

It seems `JsonUtility.FromJson` does not work for MonoBehaviour classes (and I can't get Newtonsoft to parse strings to Vector3s)

Suppose you have a MonoBehaviour class like this (so that the values can be easily specified in inspector in editor)

```
public class PropertyClass:MonoBehaviour{
  public Vector3 location;  

  public string name; 
}
```

Suppose you have json data downloaded as a string called `text`, that you try to convert to `PropertyClass[]` format via using an JSONHelper around `JSONUtility.FromJson(text);`

How do you have it autopopulate?

If you specify a FromJsonOverwrite solution - how do you have that work with JSONHelper?

````
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class JSONHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return UnityEngine.JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, **you don't**.

`MonoBehaviour` is not (de)serializable by `JsonUtility.FromJson`. Components only make sense when attached to `GameObject`s, so you can't serialize a collection of them then deserialize them into free-floating blobs unlinked from your scene and game object hierarchy.

[This behaviour is described in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html), so be sure to consult the docs for the methods you're using:

> Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the type
> you are creating must be supported by the serializer. **It must be a
> plain class/struct marked with the Serializable attribute**. Fields of
> the object must have types supported by the serializer. Fields that
> have unsupported types, as well as private fields or fields marked
> with the NonSerialized attribute, will be ignored.
>
> **Only plain classes and structures are supported**; classes derived from
> `UnityEngine.Object` (such as **`MonoBehaviour`** or `ScriptableObject`) **are not**.

[JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html), however, *will* give you the ability to deserialize JSON into the serialized fields of an *existing* MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject instance. So you can't load *new* scene content or a whole game object hierarchy this way, but you can update the properties of an object or collection of objects that already exists, while keeping their existing relationships to your various objects/scene graph intact.

Another strategy you can use is to give yourself a little serializable class or struct to hold your data, then pack that into a `MonoBehaviour`.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PropertyClassData {
    public Vector3 location;
    public string name;
}

public class PropertyClass : MonoBehaviour { 
    public PropertyClassData data; 
}
```

Now you can use JSON, XML, BinaryWriters, etc. to serialize and deserialize collections of `PropertyClassData`, which is just a "Plain Old Data Structure" with no extra methods or entanglements in your scene hierarchy that need to be navigated. That keeps the (de)serialization simple and efficient, and lets you use the `FromJson` method without a pre-existing object to overwrite into. This also removes your dependency on the built-inUnity serializer, so you're free to drop in other solutions if you need different formats than it supports

Once you have those values, you can choose to construct `GameObject`s in your scene or Assets folder with `PropertyClass` components to hold the data items. Or you can read the `data` members from a collection of existing components into a serializable collection.

The trick here is to only ask to serialize the data payload you actually want, not all the complexity that the full `MonoBehaviour` type brings along for the ride.

Comment: Okay, wish i knew this limitation for monobehaviour before i manually added a bunch of values in inspector to a few hundred gameobjects... had thought jsonOverwrite could work here

Comment: ok for now i'm just using kind of a cheap/fast trick - making ClasssnameData clones with properties only of all the previous monobehaviour classes used only for the deserialization step

Comment: JsonOverwrite does support MonoBehaviours, [as described in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html): "Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a **MonoBehaviour**, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the Serializable attribute applied." - but that's not what you showed in your question, so that's not the use case I wrote this answer for.

Comment: So why not use FromJsonOverwrite to de/serialize a MonoBehaviour to prevent having a redundant serialized data-only class?

Comment: Read the answer and find out! 